# Getting model data from controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In Ember if I have a model that is a list of users, if in the UsersController I do:

```
users = this.get('model');

users.map(function(user) {
  user.name
});
```

should it not resolve the promise and return the user records? I'm confused on why this is not working for me, or how to get the model data the correct way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind giving some more code, the route, and controller.

Comment: For context, the code you are showing works perfectly fine, but it's hard to gauge if your context is valid...  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/806/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model promise is resolved by the router. Ember, by default, sets the controller's `content` property as the route's model unless you override the route's  `setupController()` method. Your issue lies in the formatting of the map function.

It seems like you're using an array controller, because the model is an array, so do the following:

```
App.UsersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  users: function() {
    return this.map(function(user) {
      return user.get('name');
    });
  }.property('@each.user'),
});
```

You can make this code even more streamlined by using `Em.Array`'s `mapBy()` method, as follows:

```
App.UsersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  users: function() {
    return this.mapBy('name');
  }.property('@each.user'),
});
```

If you're using the list of users in your template you can do this easily with a `{{#each users}}` helper. However, if you're using this list for other properties in the controller, be sure to to use the right observer to watch for items being added to the array:

```
someOtherProperty: function() {
  var users = this.get('users');
  // Do stuff with users array here...
}.observes('users.[]')
```

See [setting up a route's model](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) and [setting up a controller](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) if you're unfamiliar with how the models stuff works.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. So if I have a property where I want to return the count of each role type that a user has, can I just do users = this.get('content') and then perform a loop over users, or would I first make a property called users where it returns this.get('content') and then reference that property from the other one? Sorry, I hope that made sense.

Comment: Also can you tell me what the .[] means exactly?

Comment: You're welcome! In a method inside an `Em.ArrayController`, `this` has methods that, for all intensive purposes, operate on the controller's content (i.e. `this.map()` is like running `this.get('content').map()`). Thus, you don't need to do `this.get('content')`. Unless I misunderstood you, I think what you're asking would be best served by a computed property on the user model - I'm not sure what you're asking though. `.[]` is a reference to `this` (and therefore `this.get('content')` but you can use it to watch when new items are added to or taken away from an `Em.Array`.

Comment: Thanks again Duncan. I might post another question that is more specific to what I am doing because I am really confused about a couple of things. You helped a lot though.

Comment: No worries - let me know if I can help you there and I will try my best!

Comment: I would love the help. I'll throw part 1 in my series of questions up.